# How can I center my form? - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a site here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/user-login/

As you can see the form is not yet centered.

The "username", "password", "remember me" are centered which must be text-aligned left.

[image]

I want to center the form and then text align left the username, password and the remember me label..using inspect element tool how can I do that?

Here's my CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #dd374d;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background: #ecf0f1; /* fallback for old browsers */
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}

.page-heading{ display: none; }
```

Please help!

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted so others know the question is solved

Comment: Anyone else here because of the cicada 3301 page that uses the same css?

Answer (score 0):

Remove *text-align: center;* from this class -

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

And add this CSS to the remember me checkbox `width: auto;`

Avoid using element level CSS specificity such as: `.form input` always use classes.

### Read more on CSS specificity:

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

And a specificity calculator: https://specificity.keegan.st/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove

> text-align: center;

from your form element.

Answer (score 0):

for text left in labels..

```
.form label{width:100%;text-align:left;}
```

And if you change the 
`<div id="content" class="col-md-9" role="main">` 
to 
`<div id="content" class="col-md-12" role="main">` 
the form will be centered.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

remove `text-align:center` form `.form` class

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

and also remove `col-md-9` class form the `div` having `content` as ID

```
<div id="content" class="col-md-9" role="main">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `text-align:center` from class `form` and change the class ub div from `col-md-9` to `col-md-12`

```
<div id="content" role="main" class="col-md-12">
 ....
</div>
```

Your Updated CSS would be

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    /* text-align:center; Remove this line */
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change no. 1-**

```
 <div id="content" class="col-md-9" role="main"></div> to

<div id="content" class="col-md-12" role="main"></div>
```

**Change no. 2-**

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
} to
.form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

**Change no. 3- Add the following Css-**

```
.login-remember label{    width: 100%;}
.form .login-remember input{width: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the form itself *is* centered inside its container `<article class="single-page-content">`.  You simply need to give that article, or actually its parent element (i.e. the div with `id=content`) full width.

For left alignment inside the form just change `text-align: center` to  `left` inside the CSS rule for `.form`

```css
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #dd374d;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background: #ecf0f1; /* fallback for old browsers */
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}

.page-heading{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="body" >
          <div class="container">
                          <div class="content-pad-3x">
                            <div class="row">
                    <div id="content" class="col-md-9" role="main">
                        <article class="single-page-content">
                         <div class="login-page">
<div class="form">
<form class="login-form">
  <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
   
   <p class="login-username">
    <label for="user_login">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" />
   </p>
   <p class="login-password">
    <label for="user_pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" />
   </p>
   
   <p class="login-remember"><label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> Remember Me</label></p>
   <p class="login-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary" value="Log In" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="" />
   </p>
   
  </form><br />
<a href="/order">Click here</a> to become a full member&#8230;<br />
<br />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```